# Matplotlib arrows being drawn incorrectly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to highlight some data in a plot with some arrows. But the arrows aren't being drawn as I would expect. The code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [.01, .1, 1, 10]
ys = [2e-20, 1e-20, 3e-19, 1e-20]

fig, ax1, = plt.subplots(1)
ax1.plot(xs, ys)

ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')

ax1.arrow(.1, 3e-19, 0, -2.4e-19)  # plot a vertical arrow at the second point pointing down from 3 to .6 x10E-19
ax1.arrow(1, 1e-20, 0, 8e-20)  # plot a vertical arrow at the third point pointing up from 1 to 9 x10E-20

plt.show()
```

produces the following image:
[image]

which is not what I'd expect, given my inputs. How can I realize the arrows I intend to draw based on the inline comments?